# Cannot send mail from an Azure VM using Gmail

Tags: email, azure, smtp, outgoing-mail

I am trying to send Email from an asp.net webform using Gmail.
the code works from my machine but when I upload the code to my windows server 2012 in Azure I get 
Unable to connect to Remote Server - exception

here is my code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.Subject = "Subject";
mail.Body = "Main body goes here";

mail.From = new MailAddress("myAcount@gmail.com");

mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;

mail.To.Add("aaaa@gmail.com");

NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("myAccount@gmail.com", "myPwd"); 
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;

smtp.Credentials = cred;
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

smtp.Send(mail);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is port 587 open on your VM?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the local VM's Firewall rules are permitting outgoing connection via port 587. [Here is a good article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj717286.aspx) on how to create outbound Firewall rule.